# Does LDAP know the login time for a specific application?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

We use LDAP to login to different applications including out service laptop. Is it possible to find out user's last login date for a specific application(in my case only one application)?
I am new to this LDAP so have no idea how things works with LDAP. Apologies if my question is stupid and does not make sense.

Comment: LDAP doesn't know about applications. You login (actually you bind) to LDAP and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most servers keep an audit log of all operations. An administrator may be able to search through the logs to identify the last time a user authenticated from an IP address (aka the application).
But otherwise, LDAP servers don't know what is the LDAP client and have no way to keep track of applications. Servers that keep track of the last login time is per user.